# Calculate a total with an input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table which has an input at the end of each row to let the user select how  many of each item they want to buy. I have made a JavaScript code that takes the data from each line of the table and makes a total price, but i can't find why it is not doing anything when i submit my form. It does show the console log but not the total which should be in my span.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>

      <tr>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['id']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Article']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Prix']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['PrixRetour']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['QuantiteeMaximale']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Projet']); ?></td>
          <td><input data-price='<?= floatval($row['Prix']); ?>' data-max-quantity='<?= intval($row['QuantiteeMaximale']); ?>' type="number" name="quantity"></td>
      </tr>

      <?php
    }

    ?>

    </table>

    <p>Grand Total: $<span id='grandTotal'></span></p>

    <script>
        console.log("test1");
        const tableEl = document.getElementById('articles')
        const grandTotalEl = document.getElementById('grandTotal')
        const quantityInputEls = tableEl.querySelectorAll('input[name=quantity]');

        (function calTotal() {
            console.log("test2");
            const updateGrandTotal = (grandTotalEl, inputEls) => {
                grandTotalEl.innerText = inputEls.reduce((total, inputEl) => {
                    const maxQuantity = parseInt(inputEl.dataset.maxQuantity)

                    if(parseInt(inputEl.value) > maxQuantity) inputEl.value = maxQuantity
                    if(parseInt(inputEl.value) < 0) inputEl.value = 0

                    const price = parseFloat(inputEl.dataset.price)
                    const quantity = parseInt(inputEl.value)

                    console.log("hello");

                    if(isNaN(quantity)) return total

                    return total + (price * quantity)

                }, 0)
            }
            console.log("test3");

            quantityInputEls.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keyup', () => updateGrandTotal(grandTotalEl, inputEls)))
        })();
    </script>

    <?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Where is the inputEls variable coming from? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @LeoFarmer that might be my problem I think I need to change quantityInputEls to inputEls